# Resources for getting started with Lucene.Net?

Tags: .net, search, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm building a simple site that allows users to post text content and I want to add it to a search index as it gets posted, so my site search is up to date.  From what I can tell Lucene.NET is a good full text search framework.  I've found very few examples of how to use it though.  Can anyone post some good references for learning about Lucene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some links:

- [Lucene tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/)
- [Another tutorial](http://darksleep.com/lucene/)
- [Lucene FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ)
- [Lucene in action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/)  The new edition should be out soon

The key point is that any Java material for Lucene is great for Lucene.net.

I should note though, that from your description of requirements, [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) might be a better fit.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Lucene.NET on Windows Azure you can check out my blog post on how to get it working with the latest Azure SDK. A lot of people have problems getting this working, so I fixed the problem and wrote an article about it: http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx