# Lucene.Net Step by Step

Tags: lucene.net

briefly I want a quick start "step by step" Example to use Lucene.Net.
My target is searching for occurrence of pair of words in huge number of documents in different formats and different language.
But Now, I want the First Step to Start :-)

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you want to search for pairs of words?

Answer (score 0):

See this SO post for good resources to get you started: [Resources for getting started with Lucene.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886456/resources-for-getting-started-with-lucene-net)

You have options for searching by pairs of words depending on what you're trying to do. If you want to search *john smith* and only match *john smith* (not *john blah blah smith*) then you can search using a [PhraseQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html).

Comment: Thanks Keith for your reply.

Comment: About pairs of words: i want to measure the semantic similarity between any two words using Corpus-based similarity (Distribution of words in large corpora). for example : Lin Algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity
Another Question: Does Lucene.Net support Arabic Language?