# Implementing search in ASP.NET MVC EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC EF6 Web App.
I've a ItemInfo table that has - ItemCode, Size, Description, CollectionName, Material and other fields. Now I've provided user search functionality for the item. I'm applying multiple contains in the search logic.
Like:

```
var results=db.ItemInfoes.Where(i=>i.ItemCode.Contains(searchString) 
|| i.Description.Contains(searchString) || i.Size.Contains(searchString) 
|| i.Material.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
```

Now, there are two issues here,

1. The search is not optimum, because if user enters a "120 mm iron", it should show from both columns(*Material and Size*) the best match. According to my logic it would show wrong results.
2. How can I show prediction/suggestion for entered search string.

I've read that enabling full text search on db and then firing sql procedure from mvc can solve the issue, I was wondering if there is a better more simpler way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is use a Search Engine lib / framework like Lucene / Elastic Search. It will provide suggestion and also other features like phonetic search, geospatial, etc.

Getting started lucene.net:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008330/1384539

Comment: Solved my purpose. Thanks.